# Not able to update code in packaging code

Tags: managed-package, security-review

In a developer org, I created a managed package and released it for security review. The security review was stopped due to few reasons.

However, I need to update the package with the new version of the files, and thereby, create a new version of the managed package. However, I am not able to import the new files via metadata API or eclipse into this org since the files are part of the package that has been released.

How do I update the package with new files? I want to use the same org since the org has the namespace that I want to finally use.

This happens with me with me in every developer org and every version of the package.

Answer (score 0):

The Managed package needs to be reverted to Beta. You need to contact salesforce support to do that.

Usually a partner or developer may request this when they realize that a package they have released needs further modification. 
A revert to Beta can only be done if the developer can confirm that the package is not installed in any organization, and that subsequent versions are also not installed in any organization. If the package is found to be installed in a subscriber org, the developer must take action to have their package uninstalled.

As an alternative from next time you can have the latest version package in your local IDE or on a version control tool to make changes and release a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

Update the files in your packaging org and create a new managed package version and upgrade the security review org to that version and let the security review people know you have done that.

That exactly represents what is going on here - you have changed some classes and that is indicated by an increment to the minor version number of your managed package.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to post a comment to Varun's answer. However, I had further questions on his answers:

Thanks for your response. You hit the nail on the head. However, this happens to me every time I create a package and release it. Should I expect Salesforce to change the release package to Beta state everytime. We plan to do one release every two weeks.

Keith, to your point, I am not able to update the files in my packaging org. That is the problem. I don't have any issue in releasing the package.